# Swift ui macOS open a new google chrome window incognito on a specific url

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, browser, swiftui

I've tried the following but it's not working.

Can you give me a hand?

Code:

```
let _ = Process.launchedProcess(
launchPath: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app", 
arguments: [" -incognito --new-window google.com"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (tested with Xcode 11.7 / macOS 10.15.6)

```
let _ = Process.launchedProcess(
   launchPath: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome", 
   arguments: ["-incognito", "--new-window google.com"]
)
```

*Note: assuming of course that your app is not sandboxed, and there is Google Chrome at that path. In real app it is better to find it dynamically.*

Comment: It doesn't work, when I click on the button to execute the code portion, the xCode error report opens.
Could the path of the browser I use be wrong?
The browser is inside the application where the App store is also located.
I am using Xcode 11.7 / macOs: 10.15.4

Comment: the error report shows:
Identifier: com.google.Chrome
So maybe the browser finds it.

Comment: Operation not permitted, Permission denied